# How to bootstrap juju on a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow, juju

I am trying to set up Kubeflow using [charmed-kubeflow](https://charmed-kubeflow.io/). It says "super easy setup" and everything. But I am failing at step 2.

Setup: "Normal" remote Kubernetes cluster, set up with Kubespray. My idea was to:

```
juju add-k8s mycluster
juju bootstrap mycluster mycluster
```

- Juju has Kubernetes access.
- Juju creates the controller.
- Juju tries to connect via 10.x.x.x IP.
- Of course setup of the Controller does NOT work.

How should this work? It is a remote cluster, private IPs cannot be accessed directly! + There is no option to configure a different Service type or so! There seem to be zero tutorials on Juju and using it... is anyone using this stuff?

Answer (score 2):

this issue with the bootstrap command has been acknowledged and a fix is included in the Juju 2.9 release.

To get a release candidate as of now, use:
`snap install juju --classic --channel=2.9/candidate`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to ensure that you use the LoadBalancer controller service type.

```
juju bootstrap --config controller-service-type=loadbalancer mycluster mycluster
```